# embedded javascript - accessing controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having an issue trying to access controls on my aspx web page via embedded javascript:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction(s, e) {

    }

   </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Within MyFunction, I am simply trying to access controls within my webpage, i.e. List Box, Drop down List etc.  When debugging through, it simply does not find a control, any control.  Throws an 'undefined' error when trying to access through a try/catch.

The controls are embedded within a

```
<dx:PopupControlContentControl>
```

Not sure if that is significant.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

solved.  I did not specify ClientInstanceName on the control.